# Using Where-Object to find files created within time range

Tags: powershell, filter, time

all. I'm trying to take the creation date of a file in one folder and use it to filter files in another while also making sure they contain the phrase 'MS'. This is what I have so far:

```
$MSdat_time = $MSdat_file.CreationTime


# Defining maximum and minimum auto save creation times with a window of +/- 5 min
$auto_maxtime = ($MSdat_time).AddMinutes(5)
$auto_mintime = ($MSdat_time).AddMinutes(-5)

# Locating any Auto Save files created within time frame using 'MS' pattern as a parameter in case of multiple files
$autsav_file = Get-ChildItem  "\\IP.Address\Test Data\Auto Saves" | `
  Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -ge $auto_mintime) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -le $auto_maxtime)} | `
  Select-String -Pattern 'MS' | Select-Object -Unique Path
```

I put in 'IP address' as a place holder. So far, it's returning nothing even though I know a file with those parameters exists and this section of code was working fine yesterday.

Comment: If it was working, but now isn't, I'd verify that `Get-ChildItem  "\\IP.Address\Test Data\Auto Saves"` returns the correct starting set of files in the first place. If it does, there's something wrong with your filtering. If it doesn't, something's gone wrong targeting the directory at all - either the IP address has changed or is otherwise invalid, or the path is no longer what you think it is, or your privileges are now somehow insufficient.

Comment: "this section of code was working fine yesterday" - that's how time works - if you updated the file 24 hours and 5 minutes ago, the script would have output it 24 hours ago, but not now (because the duration between then and now is more than 5 minutes)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the time is being pulled from a file creation time, not the current time. am i missing something in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your `$MSdat_file` variable has a value. It could be that your previous PS sessions had given that variable a value outside of your script.

After assigning `$MSdat_file = Get-Item "./out.wav"`, I was able to get expected output:

```
PS /Users/ethansmith> /Users/ethansmith/Documents/test.ps1
PS /Users/ethansmith> $autsav_file

Path
----
/Users/ethansmith/Documents/test.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help! @ethan was right, the issue was with my $MSdat_file variable having an old value saved to it. Should have traced my code back to the beginning sooner haha. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please post your appreciate message as a comment under the answer.